# Django Multiple DB with Contenttype table

Tags: django

well, I am implementing a multiple db feature on an exist django project. After I create and setup the secondary db to django, the first thing I did is running syncdb and migrate, which will create a lot built-in django tables, includes django_content_type table.

Then I realize, the records in the new django_content_type table are different from the one in primary db. To be more specific, the primary key is different.

Let's say I have a record in primary db django_content_type table looks like following:

```
 id | name | app_label | model 
----+------+-----------+-------
 33 | Tag  | taggit    | tag
```

However, after syncdb and running migrations, I got following in my secondary db:

```
 id | name | app_label | model 
----+------+-----------+-------
 11 | Tag  | entities  | tag
```

I kind of hate to have two inconsistent django_content_type sitting in my two db. I tried to truncate one of them and load a fixture from another and failed, since django_content_type table is referred by most of other tables.

What is best way to handle things like this? I try to convince myself this won't matter, but I am afraid inconsistency will bite me in the future, so I really want to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a common issue since you are using different databases. The main concern here is when some models are using `ContentType` as a field which will be translated to an `FK` like `content_type_object_id` in the database, and when those are different in the databases might cause an error. Therefore, because you need two databases in your application you should manager your calls using `db_manager()` not `using()`

For example:

In your application, this might cause an error

```
ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Tag)
```

Because you are using a manager method `get_for_model()` and you need to specify the database before.

```
ContentType.objects.db_manager(...).get_for_model(Tag)
```

In this way you will make sure that you are getting the ContentType based on the PK that has been addressed in the specified database.

---

I am not saying that there is no solution, there might be a solution to sync  the two databases. However, I wrote this to not worry you about the situation.

I really prefer that they would be consistent, but multiple databases never do to me.

Comment: Seems a reasonable answer, though I really want to get those pk consistent cross databases. I will dig deeper and see if there is a solution. Thank you.